# Problems with unzipping .tar.gz

Tags: installation, directory, tar, gzip

For installations i've needed to unzip .tar.gz so ive used
  `tar fvxz  file_name.tar.gz`
yet it replies with

```
tar (child): file_name.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

what should i do?

Comment: Please provide a link to the instructions you are using.

Comment: Find where the tar.gz file is, and then copy it, and paste in place of `file_name.tar.gx` - you may need to remove `file://` from the beginning. Can't you open it and press extract, or right click and press 'Extract Here'. The error message it is outputting is saying it cannot find the file, as there is no file called `file_name.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal error message stating the file does NOT exist. I get the same reply if I issue that command at a random location:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ tar fvxz file_name.tar.gz
tar (child): file_name.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

If you got the extraction instruction from a site you probably need to change "file_name" to the actual name of the download. It sounds like a generic command for extracting a tar.gz file.